# Parse javascript api not working on heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, parse-platform

My question is self explanatory in the title. I'm using parse within rails. When I test the parse api locally, the test object works just fine. However, the same line of code with a newly parse initialize key(emphasis) will not work on the heroku server. Anyone have ideas why this might be? Thanks in advanced.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.15.min.js">          </script>
<h1>New Meal Request</h1>
```

```
 <h2>Quantity</h2>
<select id="quant" class="form-control">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  </select>
   <input id="mealReq"type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Meal instructions">




                     <h3> You are seen as: <%= current_user.full_name %>
                        </h3>
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 Parse.initialize("XXX","XXX");
 var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("TestObject");
 var testObject = new TestObject();
 testObject.save({foo: "bar"}, {
 success: function(object) {
 alert("yay! it worked");
 }
});
```

Comment: Please provide details on the error like a stack trace.

Comment: I got an error that looks something like this: Uncaught ReferenceError: Parse is not defined new:88
(anonymous function)

Comment: not sure what it exactly means. Maybe I need to look into something like backbone.js?

Comment: For some reason, it looks like your page isn't fetching `Parse` from the CDN. Look for a 404. Also, you might have an issue with how you have set up your API key in `production.rb`.